# no space between images in inline display images (xhtml2pdf)

Tags: html, css, django, xhtml2pdf

I am using `xhtml2pdf` to generate PDF file from my DetailView in Django. I have a loop in my html template file where I am displaying all images in 1 line.

What I am struggling with is adding some space between images and either `padding, padding-left, padding-right, margin, margin-left, margin-right` don't work in inline display. They only work if I put images in seperate lines. I do the same on my website and the padding works fine but not in my pdf.

I've read in the documentation that there is no way to use images within paragraphs so images are always rendered in seperate paragraphs (link for reference is [here](https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#position-floating)).

**Question:**

Is there any way in `xhtml2pdf` to add space between images if I want to keep them in 1 line? I am looking for some tips, hacks, or any solution to this problem.

my loop in HTML file

```
<div>
{% for client in product.client.all %}
    <img src="{% thumbnail client.client_logo 125x100 upscale %}" alt="{{client.title}}" class="client-logos">
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

utils.py

```
def export_to_pdf(request, slug):
  product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug, status=1)
  template_path = 'card_pdf_template.html'
  teams = Team.objects.filter(product__slug=slug)
  context = {'product': product, 'teams': teams}
  response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
  response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename={product}.pdf'.format(product=product)
  template = get_template(template_path)
  html = template.render(context)
  # create a pdf
  pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(
     html, dest=response)
  if pisa_status.err:
     return HttpResponse('We had some errors <pre>' + html + '</pre>')
  return response
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work for you but I am displaying images with a table and creating space with this code:

```
<tr>
    <td><p><img class="scale-with-grid" src="{{cleaning.image1.path}}"/></p></td>
    <td><p><img class="scale-with-grid" src="{{cleaning.image2.path}}"/></p></td>
    <td><p><img class="scale-with-grid" src="{{cleaning.image3.path}}"/></p></td>
    <td><p><img class="scale-with-grid" src="{{cleaning.image4.path}}"/></p></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: For this code to create space, you'd also need the appropriate CSS, wouldn't you?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did not add any css for my template to work but, this link may help more then the code I used. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_grid_responsive.asp) or [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-an-image-gallery-with-css-grid-e0f0fd666a5c/)